# Twitter OAuth encodes url different

Tags: .net, twitter

I'm calling status update from .NET and when I post a tweet with no spaces or special chars it posts ok but when there are other special chars I get a different OAuth Signature base string, Twitter Oauth tool shows this for *status=Hello world*:

```
status%3DHello%2520world
```

While .NET Uri.EscapeDataString(post_body) shows:

```
status%3DHello%20world
```

This result in a 401 unauthorized as OAuth signatures are different.

How can I solve this? (Actually, Twitter codification for space does not seem any standard)

Thank you

Comment: %25 seems encoding for % itself!! why does twitter do this?

Comment: So finally I solved url enconding twice only the parameter contents, i.e, status in this case.

Comment: Well, sometimes it works double enconding only status content, but still have some problems with chars like "!"

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is following the spec..  depending on where the encoding end point is.

1. URL encode the keys and values.  Both you and twitter get this
   right.  You'll see:
2. Sort by key than value.  Join each key and
   value by an '=', and join this to the others via an '&'.  Since
   there are no '&'s, this does nothing.  I'm guessing here since I
   haven't used this twitter tool.
3. Encode this whole string.

   "status=hello%20world" -> "status%3Dhello%2520world"